# Cannot Search and Delete the Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree, singly-linked-list

my teammate had been searching the problem of our this program for 2 days, this program supposely to delete the information base on the Author Name that input by the user. At the same time the user need to search the information based on the Author Name that input by the user but suddenly the program turn to b error and stop. Somebody who expert in C, I need your guidance.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    char title[50], author[50], ISBN[50], pubDate[20];
    struct node* left, * right;
};

struct node* insert_node(struct node* root, char author[], char title[], char ISBN[], char pubDate[]);
struct node* FindMin(struct node*);

void in_display(struct node* root);
void search(struct node* root, char searchAuthor[]);
struct node* delete_node(struct node*, char deleteAuthor[]);

void main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    int ch;
    char title[50], author[50], ISBN[50], pubDate[20], deleteAuthor[50], searchAuthor[50];
    do
    {
        printf("\n1.Insert a new Boook Record");
        printf("\n2.Display all the Books record");
        printf("\n3.Delete a Book Record");
        printf("\n4.Search a abook Record ");
        printf("\n5.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:printf("\nEnter the author of the book\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &author);
            printf("\nEnter the title of the book\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &title);
            printf("\nKey in the ISBN code\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &ISBN);
            printf("\nEnter the Publication Date of the book\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &pubDate);
            root = insert_node(root, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
            break;
        case 2:
            in_display(root);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nEnter the author of the book to be deleted\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &deleteAuthor);
            root = delete_node(root, deleteAuthor);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\nEnter the author of the book to be searched\t");
            scanf("\n%[^\n]%*c", &searchAuthor);
            search(root, searchAuthor);
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
}
struct node* insert_node(struct node* root, char author[], char title[], char ISBN[], char pubDate[])
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(temp->author, author);
        strcpy(temp->title, title);
        strcpy(temp->ISBN, ISBN);
        strcpy(temp->pubDate, pubDate);
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    if (author <= root->author)
    {
        root->left = insert_node(root->left, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = insert_node(root->right, author, title, ISBN, pubDate);
    }
    return root;
}
void in_display(struct node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    in_display(root->left);
    printf("\nAuthor Name - %s", root->author);
    printf("\nBook Title - %s", root->title);
    printf("\nISBN - %s", root->ISBN);
    printf("\nPublication Date - %s\n", root->pubDate);
    in_display(root->right);
}
struct node* delete_node(struct node* root, char deleteAuthor[]) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return root;
    }
    else if (deleteAuthor < root->author) {
        root->left = delete_node(root->left, deleteAuthor);
    }
    else if (deleteAuthor > root->author) {
        root->right = delete_node(root->right, deleteAuthor);
    }
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
        else if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else {
            struct node* temp = root;
            root->left = FindMin(root);
            root->left->right = root->right;
            root = root->left;
            strcpy(temp->author, root->author);
            strcpy(temp->title, root->title);
            strcpy(temp->ISBN, root->ISBN);
            strcpy(temp->pubDate, root->pubDate);
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
        }
        return root;
    }
    return root;
}

struct node* FindMin(struct node* root) {
    while (root->left != NULL) {
        root = root->left;
    }
    return root;
}

void search(struct node* root, char searchAuthor[]) {
    if (root->author > searchAuthor) {
        search(root->left, searchAuthor);
    }
    else if (root->author < searchAuthor) {
        search(root->right, searchAuthor);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nAuthor Name - %s", root->author);
        printf("\nBook Title - %s", root->title);
        printf("\nISBN - %s", root->ISBN);
        printf("\nPublication Date - %s\n", root->pubDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a short input sequence that shows the error. Explain what happens and what you expected to happen

Answer (score 0):

```
if (author <= root->author)
```

is not comparing the two strings - it compares two pointers.

Use `strcmp` instead.

```
if (strcmp(author, root->author) <= 0)
```

This also applies to other places in the code, e.g.

```
else if (deleteAuthor < root->author)
```

is also wrong.

BTW: When using `scanf` to scan into a char array, you don't need put `&` in front of the array name. Just use the array name directly.

Comment: i changed from
"if (deleteAuthor < root->author)"    TO
"if (strcmp(searchAuthor, root->author) < 0)"
but I kept getting error when search not found. I dont know whether my if else statement problem or anything